# How does quadratic convergence imply linear convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Linear convergence of a sequence is present if there exists a $c$ with $0<c<1$ such that  $$|x_{k+1}-x| \leq c|x_{k}-x|, k=0,1,...$$ with $x$ being the limit of the sequence.

Quadratic convergence of a sequence is present if there exists a $c$ with $0<c<1$ such that $$|x_{k+1}-x| \leq c|x_{k}-x|^{2}, k=0,1,... $$

Further it is said that quadratic convergence implies linear convergence.

All of this is according to the [german wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konvergenzgeschwindigkeit).

My question is: How can quadratic convergence imply linear convergence? To me it seems as if it is actually the other way round. After all, if you drop the ^2 then you are left with the formula for linear convergence meaning that there are sequences that fall into the definition of quadratic convergence but not into the definition of linear convergence because the formula for quadratic convergence is less restrictive.

Comment: The formula for quadratic convergence is _more_ restictive if $|x_k - x| < 1$, which is bound to hold eventually by definition of convergence.

Comment: $|x_k-x|<1$ for big $k$; so, $|x_k-x|^2 < |x_k-x|$, and $|x_{k+1}-x|\le c |x_k-x|^2 < c |x_k-x|$

Comment: What I'm worried about is the "$k = 0,1,2,\ldots$" part. That doesn't feel like it belongs in a convergence criterion. I would rather it said "there is a $K \in \Bbb N$ so that this holds for all $k > K$". As written, the eventually (almost immediately) constant sequence $1, 2, 0,0,0,\ldots$ isn't even _linearly_ convergent.